# how to fetch array of data from database and store it in variable using PHP

Tags: php, database

```html
published

0
1
1
0
1
0
0
```

I have a table column called published in my database....it have 0 and 1 . Now what I want is I want to select those array of data from that column and store it in variable called $result.

Comment: anyone help guys

Comment: you wanna $result = 0110100 ?